# all urls displayed normally in webview except this one

Tags: java, android, android-webview

I'm trying to display a webpage in my WebView, it was working fine until yesterday, now it is displaying only blank. The issue is that the link opens fine in chrome and firefox and all other links works also fine in my webview, what seems to be the issue? i guess i'm missing something in the configuration of my app?

here is the url : https://morocco.blsspainvisa.com/book_appointment.php

I tried a random browser project from github and it was having the same issue as me, so maybe the website have changed some restrictions?

```
    WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    webSettings.setUseWideViewPort(true);

    webSettings.setSupportZoom(true);
    webSettings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    webSettings.setDisplayZoomControls(false);

    mWebView.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);
    mWebView.setScrollbarFadingEnabled(false);
    webSettings.setRenderPriority(WebSettings.RenderPriority.HIGH);

    mWebView.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);
    mWebView.setScrollbarFadingEnabled(false);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
        mWebView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null);
    } else {
        mWebView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
    }
    String newUA= "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.0.4) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/4.0";
    webSettings.setUserAgentString(newUA);

    mWebView.loadUrl("https://morocco.blsspainvisa.com/book_appointment.php");
    mWebView.addJavascriptInterface(new webAppInterface(this),"Android");
    mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient(){..};
    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){..}
```

Comment: Have you tried remote debugging the WebView? https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging/webviews?hl=en

Comment: @axierjhtjz no i haven't yet, i'll try it now and then post the message, thank you

Comment: @axierjhtjz it displays an empty webpage :
<html><head></head><body></body></html>

Comment: Take a look at the console for js errors. Also paste the logcat to see if anything is failing on the proccess of loading the WebView.

Comment: @axierjhtjz the console isn't showing anything but this : Navigated to https://morocco.blsspainvisa.com/book_appointment.php
And the logcat not showing any error too except of this one "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'value' of null", source:  (1) which is in the onPageFinished function

Comment: if i change **morocco** by **tunisia** ( which are bsaically the same website ) the page will load just fine, but if i keep it, it doesn't load in my app but loads just fine in all browsers